# ArrayList using hashmap not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, arraylist

I have this code where I get the data from `Facebook Graph API` which seems working, my problem is when i add the hashmap to my arraylist its not working, i toasted the size of my array and I always get zero. please help. here is the code:

```
public class PageFeedHome extends Fragment {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> feedList;
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private String feedMessage;
ListView listView;
BaseAdapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_home_activity,
            container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_lv);
    feedList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    new LoadPosts().execute();


    return view;
}

private class LoadPosts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true,
                new Session.StatusCallback() {

                    // callback when session changes state
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                            Exception exception) {
                        if (session.isOpened()) {

                            new Request(session, "/163340583656/feed",
                                    null, HttpMethod.GET,
                                    new Request.Callback() {
                                        public void onCompleted(
                                                Response response) {
                                            /* handle the result */
                                            Log.i("PostFeedResponse", response.toString());
                                            try {
                                                GraphObject graphObj = response
                                                        .getGraphObject();
                                                JSONObject json = graphObj
                                                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                                                JSONArray jArray = json
                                                        .getJSONArray("data");
                                                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                                    JSONObject currObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                    final String feedId = currObj.getString("id");
                                                    if (currObj.has("message")) {
                                                        feedMessage = currObj.getString("message");
                                                    } else if (currObj.has("story")) {
                                                        feedMessage = currObj.getString("story");
                                                    } else {
                                                        feedMessage = "Posted a something";
                                                    }
                                                    JSONObject fromObj = currObj.getJSONObject("from");
                                                    String from = fromObj.getString("name");

                                                    HashMap<String, String> feed = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                                    feed.put(TAG_ID, feedId);
                                                    feed.put(TAG_MESSAGE, feedMessage);
                                                    feed.put(TAG_NAME, from);

                                                    feedList.add(feed);
                                                    Log.i("added" , feedList.toString());
                                                }
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }).executeAsync();
                        }
                    }
                });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+feedList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), feedList,
                R.layout.feed_item_view, new String[] { TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_NAME,
                TAG_ID }, new int[] { R.id.message, R.id.author, R.id.id_tv });

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you closing your for loop ?

Comment: Have you checked via debugger if it's an asynchronous problem?

Comment: @Smutje yes, its seems there's no error.

Comment: @maveňツ after feedList.add(feed);
              Log.i("added" , feedList.toString());